# Merge a oracle table from different database having join condition on primary key generated using sequence

Tags: oracle11g

I have a table that needs to merge from same table in another database.

Condition is one of the column in composite primary key is generated by sequence and may differ in another database.

How can we sync remaining columns in this situation?

Ex.
DB1:
Table: SRE_SERVICE_OPTION
Columns:(OPTION_SET_ID, OPTION_NAME, OPTION_VALUE, VALUE_ORDER)

DB2:
Table: SRE_SERVICE_OPTION
Columns:(OPTION_SET_ID, OPTION_NAME, OPTION_VALUE, VALUE_ORDER)

Primary key:
OPTION_SET_ID, OPTION_NAME, VALUE_ORDER

How should I write merge statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've made the classic error in a distributed database. Simply put, by using two separate sequences you have an inconsistent primary key across the tables. You will only be able to use MERGE if your tables are *both* separately unique on `OPTION_NAME`, `OPTION_VALUE` and `VALUE_ORDER`.

Your only other hope is that your tables do not contain any duplicated information between them. If so you can simply insert from one into the other.

Otherwise, you are, I'm afraid out of luck. I would re-design your database so that it's impossible to send duplicated information into two different tables with separate, inconsistent, surrogate keys.

Comment: Ben, Thanks a lot for quick response. Let me explain the scenario in details that will help more to under stand the requirement.

Comment: I have customer using product release 7.0 and he wants to migrate latest release 8.0. I have created reference database 8.0 that has all the changes in this table made till now including 7.1,7.2 etc as well.Now as part of automation I want to merge latest changes in this table to customer table so that customer table have all the new data related to product and will not remove any customer specific data. So in this case I can't use same sequence in both databases.Also other fields are not separately unique.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't see how this changes my answer. If you have two separate sequences populating a table you will not be able to keep the two tables in sync. Rather than creating a new _table_ why not create a view on the old one, which may help solve your problem until you complete the migration.

Comment: Thanks for the help Ben. I have written manual inserts/updates/deletes as both databases created for different purposes so I think view will not suffice the requirement here.